# React Native expo project with Firebase not building with eas build

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, eas

I have a react native project that uses expo. I have Firebase setup for DB. I am trying to build the project using eas build in order to deploy it to the app store. The build keeps failing on me and I am unsure how to fix it.

Here is the end of the build where it says it is failing. I have provided the app.json file below that I have setup for the project.

```
› Executing calculator » [CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock
› Executing calculator » Start Packager on http://localhost:8081
› Executing calculator » [Expo] Configure project
› Copying   ios/calculator/Supporting/Expo.plist ➜ ./Expo.plist
› Compiling calculator » SplashScreen.storyboard
› Preparing calculator » Info.plist
› Compiling calculator » main.m
› Compiling calculator » calculator_vers.c
› Compiling calculator » AppDelegate.mm
› Linking   calculator » calculator
⚠️  ld: method '+moduleName' in category from /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/calculator-fxwyvqgdekbzjhfokipkknhjelmw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/calculator/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/ExpoModulesCore/ExpoModulesCore.framework/ExpoModulesCore(ExpoBridgeModule-acfbb23c8b4083dfdb5ac41fb4f5357d.o) overrides method from class in /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/calculator-fxwyvqgdekbzjhfokipkknhjelmw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/calculator/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/ExpoModulesCore/ExpoModulesCore.framework/ExpoModulesCore(ExpoBridgeModule-69a9b509dd25ae137b098ea769004bb2.o)
› Generating debug calculator » calculator.app.dSYM
› Executing calculator » Bundle React Native code and images
    Bundler cache is empty, rebuilding (this may take a minute)

❌  error: File /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/calculator-fxwyvqgdekbzjhfokipkknhjelmw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/calculator/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/calculator.app/main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with React Native, please report it here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues

▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
▸ The following build commands failed:
▸   PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/calculator-fxwyvqgdekbzjhfokipkknhjelmw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/calculator/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/calculator.build/Release-iphoneos/calculator.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh (in target 'calculator' from project 'calculator')
▸ (1 failure)
2024-01-22 09:31:13.362 xcodebuild[2052:8042] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/calculator-fxwyvqgdekbzjhfokipkknhjelmw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/calculator/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/calculator.build/Release-iphoneos/calculator.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh (in target 'calculator' from project 'calculator')
(1 failure)
Exit status: 65
+-------------+-------------------------+
|           Build environment           |
+-------------+-------------------------+
| xcode_path  | /Applications/Xcode.app |
| gym_version | 2.213.0                 |
| sdk         | iPhoneOS16.4.sdk        |
+-------------+-------------------------+
Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project
It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how
to troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/
Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make
sure your project is set up correctly.
fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the
the full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.
Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there
[!] Error building the application - see the log above
Error: The "Run fastlane" step failed with an unknown error. Refer to "Xcode Logs" below for additional, more detailed logs.
















  {
  "expo": {
    "name": "calculator",
    "slug": "calculator",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/Vector.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/Vector.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "hidden"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/Vector.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "hidden"
      },
      "firebase": {
        "apiKey": "hidden",
        "authDomain": "hidden",
        "projectId": "hidden",
        "storageBucket": "hidden",
        "messagingSenderId": "hidden",
        "appId": "hidden",
        "measurementId": "hidden"
      }
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "compileSdkVersion": 31,
            "targetSdkVersion": 31,
            "buildToolsVersion": "31.0.0"
          },
          "ios": {
            "deploymentTarget": "13.4",
            "useFrameworks": "static"
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are building locally. If so, try to clean the Xcode cache following this: [How to Empty Caches and Clean All Targets Xcode 4 and later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4-and-later).

If it doesn't work still, try to build with Expo server (so don't use the --local flag)